# @media rules not working

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to apply some CSS to work only on mobile devices, here is my code below:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1081px;) {
 #messageText
  {
   font-size:6px !important;
  }
}
```

some text here

It does not however, appear to be working, when I select the `messageText` div element in Chrome dev tools, `font-size` does not appear anywhere, not even crossed out. This makes me think that the element is not being applied for some reason, rather then being overwritten. Can anyone tell why? I tried looking on my IPhone 6 in Safari and Emulating IPhone 4 in Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1081px) {
  #messageText {
   font-size: 6px !important;
  }
}
```

You don't need the extra `;` you have inside the `max-width: 1081px` block.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Use like below:-

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1081px) {
   #messageText
    {
    font-size:6px !important;
     }
   }
```

This will work.